# Phonegap: keypress event not fired on Android

Tags: cordova

I am working on converting a web app to Android app using Phonegap. keypress event is not firing when I press a key on keyboard. I noticed that keydown event is fired instead of keypress but with keyCode and charCode always 0. Please help.

My code is:

```
    if (document.addEventListener){
        console.log("****** document.addEventListener ******");
        document.addEventListener("keydown",UI.keydown,false);
        document.addEventListener("keypress",UI.keypress,false);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent)
    {
        console.log("****** document.attachEvent ******");
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", UI.keydown);
        document.attachEvent("onkeypress", UI.keypress);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("****** document.onkeypress ******");
        document.onkeydown= UI.keydown;
        document.onkeypress= UI.keypress;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I have always used `keyup` for this. Here is an example:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', getInput, false);

function getInput(e){
    keyData = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dawson, keyup is fired but still I am getting 0 in keyCode, charCode, and which