# Get Correct Input From KeyCode 229

Tags: android

I have come across the android problem where if you type using the Android virtual keyboard the keycode passed on the keypress and keyup event is 229, I have been looking for a tutorial on how to get the correct key code from the key being pressed. I know that different methods use split or conflate models but I need a tutorial on both as it has to work on all Android devices.

This is how I get the keycode, I just call e.whcih

```
document.getElementById("textarea").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    keypressfunction
}, false);
document.getElementById("textarea").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keydownfunction
}, false);
document.getElementById("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keyupfucntion
}, false);
```

Comment: Please paste in the code you're currently using.

Comment: Right now, how r u getting the keyCode. Can you please share the code with this question?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)