# Is it possible to detect when a user is typing with a predictive keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I need to execute some code every time the user writes in a textarea. Currently, I am listening for a `keyup`-event, but the latest years predictive keyboards has become normal on mobile devices. This does not trigger my event handler. It also does not get triggered when the user uses right click to paste text into the textarea.

Is there any event that let's me execute code also when the user changes the content of the textarea without pressing keys?

Comment: Have you tried the onchange event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea onchange detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection)

Comment: @Michiel That doesn't fire on every change, usually only when the element loses focus

Comment: That is absolutely true. For a full answer, you should check the duplicate link above. It suggest using a combination of keyup and change events, with links to code samples.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the `oninput` event, as per this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33646354/679240

Comment: @Michiel I agree with the dupe - but the [not-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14029861/791010) on that question is the one to go for.  Removed my answer here in deference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me, since I was using AngularJS for this project, was using `$scope.$watch`. This allows a function to be triggered every time a variable in the scope changes, and will trigger also when the user is using a predictive keyboard.