# Android numeric keyboard keypress not triggered

Tags: android, html, angularjs, android-softkeyboard

I created a simple AngularJs directive which add a bind to "keypress" event:

```
app.directive('filterInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

            elem.bind('keypress', function(e) {
                alert(e.code || e.which);
            })

            elem.on('keypress', function(e) {
                alert(e.code || e.which);
            })

        }
    }
})
```

Just for test there are both "bind" and "on" hooks. This works fine for iOS devices. However In Android, if you press a comma, enter or whatever is not a number the event won't fire.

[working JSFiddle, open it on Android device](http://jsfiddle.net/mudokp0x/)

**Update**:

I added:

```
elem.on('input', function(e) {
    alert(e.code || e.which);
})
```

and now the event is firing for all keys (bytheway the event code is undefined) except for enter (keycode 13). Unfortunately I need to intercept exactly that key.

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)