# In Quilljs Editor, How to insert an undeletable block-level element?

Tags: javascript, quill

Here I customize a block element by `Quill.import('blots/block/embed')` which I insert into the editor content. I would like to know that if there is any way to make it undeletable, therefore the user could not **delete it** or **edit it**? Thanks a lot.

Comment: upvote, i have a similar use case, but for email signatures/powered by strap lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the solution I came up with was to intercept the keyboard binding for backspace. In the example here I have a custom 'video' blot. So, if backspace is entered and the cursor is on or directly after a video, it does nothing. Here is the documentation for the Keyboard Module for reference: https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/

```
let _this = this;    
this.quill = new Quill(this.contentElement, {
  modules: {
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
        video: {
          key: 'backspace',
          handler: function(range, keycontext) {
            let format = _this.quill.getFormat(range.index - 1);
            if (!format.video && !keycontext.format.video) {
              // propogate to Quill's default
              return true;
            } // else do nothing to prevent deleting video
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

Also, another thing to keep in mind, the editor has contenteditable="true", which your custom blot will inherit. So you'll probably want to set contenteditable="false" on the node in your custom blot.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for Android GBoard or similar soft-keyboards. Due to the fact that autocorrect / completion etc might change the text, none of the soft keyboards send keyup or keydown, and they'll always send 0. Try this on android with GBoard in chrome, and you'll sadly see it won't work – because of this specific issue : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

and related to this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript