# JavaScript: block backspace on text input on Android

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to block all input on an html text field with jQuery. The following solution works on desktop browsers:

```
that.input.keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

However, while it blocks regular input it fails to block backspace on Android (Chrome). I've also tried blocking the keyup and keypress events, but that didn't help. I don't want to set the readonly attribute, because I intend to allow the input in certain situations.

Is there any clean solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I don't want to set the readonly attribute, because I intend to allow the input in certain situations."* Why don't you change the `readonly` value on those *"certain situations"*?

Comment: I can't, because this will be determined as you type. If I set the readonly attribute the cursor will disappear and so will the virtual keyboard on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is that android keyboards are not keyboards. When a text field is opened in android the text-field-owner application and the keyboard application, speaking simply, come to share a resource which is the text field contents. The keyboard app receives the entire contents of the text field and then edits - including deletions - are made locally and pushed to the app via calls like DeleteSurroundingText (for simple deletions of non-text content i.e. whitespace) or setComposingRegion/setComposingText for changes to words. This means that autocorrect can work on already-existing words.

Some android keyboards generate keypress events which reach Chrome, some do not. Sometimes it makes no sense to generate keypress events - if a word is autocorrected what keypresses should be sent?

As you are looking for the keyboard and cursor to be displayed but the field to remain uneditable until later I would suggest you implement some sort of onChange/Revert loop.

[Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery/2885716#2885716)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently android keyboards have a strange bug with the keyboard so instead of attaching to the keydown event maybe try the [oninput](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event.

I found more info on this issue here [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately, this event is not cancellable. I can use it to capture the key press, but I can't block it. Cancellable events (like keydown) can block all input, but they fail with backspace on Android.

Comment: maybe reset the input to the last value?

Comment: Looks like it might end up being the only solution. I was hoping there might be something else I'm not seeing. Ah well, thanks for the help anyway!