# Why is "Unidentified" returned on mobile?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to alert the key which was pressed. It is working on PC but returning "Unidentified" on mobile. Why is that?

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
     alert(e.key);
   });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Comment: @sfarbota no, i am not working with input fields, i want to capture all the keystrokes, not just on specified input fields

Comment: You should be using the `input` event or touch events. There are no keys on a mobile device.

Comment: @Scott Marcus yes, but the virtual keyboard seems to have keycodes which can be converted to unicode characters using `.key`.

Comment: I ran to similar problem on scan code readers: keys were marked as "unidentified" due to wrong system settings which mapped the scanning to virtual keyboard. It was on Android 10 and Chrome and when properly set, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug in Chrome on Android. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229) and [the official bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639). I wish I had better news for you, but it looks like you can't rely on keyboard triggers in web apps on Android if you need to capture the individual key values.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is catch the e.target.value:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  var inputValue = e.target.value;
  var lastLetter = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length - 1);
  alert('Letter: ' + lastLetter);
});
```