# angular flxng mention cannot open auto suggestion in Android Chrome

Tags: angular, mention

I am trying to use [flxng mentions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flxng/mentions) in my angular project

but when I testing my project in android mobile chrome

the auto suggestion didn't popup after I type '@'

however I can get the auto suggestion in desktop Chrome and even in iOS safari

So how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did check the chrome versions?

Comment: It is Android 11, Chrome 93.0.4577.62

I also checked another phone, also not work: 
Android 10, Chrome 91.0.4472.164

Comment: I find that it may related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584061/why-is-unidentified-returned-on-mobile