# Java Script Validation not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, mobile, browser

I am trying to make validation to accept only numbers (no letters), It works on the computer browser but stopes when using the mobile browser.
**Below is the code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    const $input = document.querySelector("#phMidPane_ctl04_txtID");
    const NUMBER_ALLOWED_CHARS_REGEXP = /[0-9\/]+/;
    $input.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
      console.log(NUMBER_ALLOWED_CHARS_REGEXP.test(event.key));
      if (!NUMBER_ALLOWED_CHARS_REGEXP.test(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
    $input.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
      // alert(2);
      if (!NUMBER_ALLOWED_CHARS_REGEXP.test(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673783/1772933

Comment: Listen to the `change` event. That event will be triggered whenever the `value` of the input changes, which will also fire on mobile.

Comment: Keypress event isn't really intended for mobile, some OS can deal with it but really you want to be listening for an event like `textInput` or `change`

Comment: @DavidAlsbright you meant `input` instead of `textInput` right? `textInput` is deprecated.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes. Coffee levels are low right now, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright `change` event doesn't fire until the control loses focus. Only `input` ;)